# Return value if row contains specific text

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
  ID Combination 
1  1        Blue        
2  2         Red        
3  3       Green        
4  4 Blue, Green        
5  5  Green, Red        
6  6   Red, Blue
```

I tried to create a new column "New" that will display "it has green" when the word "green" is inside "Combination" and "no green" when the word is not inside.

```
df$New = ifelse(df$Combination <= "Green", "it has green", "no green")

  ID Combination          New
1  1        Blue it has green
2  2         Red     no green
3  3       Green it has green
4  4 Blue, Green it has green
5  5  Green, Red     no green
6  6   Red, Blue     no green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gan use `grepl()` to find out whether a word appears in your value:

```
df$New = "no green"
df$New[grepl("Green",df$Combination)] = "it has green"
```

This first creates the default case (no green) and then transforms all values corresponding to combinations containing "Green".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can try using `grepl`

```
within(
  df,
  New <- c("no green", "it has green")[1 + grepl("green", Combination, ignore.case = TRUE)]
)
```

such that

```
  ID Combination          New
1  1        Blue     no green
2  2         Red     no green
3  3       Green it has green
4  4 Blue, Green it has green
5  5  Green, Red it has green
6  6   Red, Blue     no green
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, Combination = c("Blue", "Red", "Green", 
"Blue, Green", "Green, Red", "Red, Blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach uses logical comparisons for text, which, in this case, will give you true whenever the first letter of your vector is `<=` to the first letter of "Green". Kind of a weird comparison!

To make this better for text comparisons, you'd want to use something more friendly to character vectors.

You could use the `stringr::str_contains` function, which would allow you to do this, or you could use built in regex support like `grepl` which checks your vector for the string "green" and returns `TRUE` if it finds it.

Here is how you could do the latter:

```
df <- data_frame(Combination = c("Blue",
                                 "Red",
                                 "Green",
                                 "Blue, Green",
                                 "Green, Red",
                                 "Red, Blue"))
df$new <- ifelse(grepl(pattern = "Green", df$Combination), "it has green", "no green")
df
```

Comment: No wonder it was giving me inconsistent result in my "New" column. Thanks Brian